# sqlite3 : near "(": syntax error - python code

Tags: python, sqlite

I am getting a syntax error for this query and am unable to figure out what mistake I made in this.

```
db = sqlite3.connect('C:\Users\Siva Sakthi Velan\Downloads\Intranet\mobiveil.db')
sql = """select cast(sum(datediff(second,0,Total_Hours))/3600 as varchar(12)) + ':' +right( '0' + cast(sum(datediff(second,0,Total_Hours))/60%60 as varchar(2)),2) +':' + right('0' + cast(sum(datediff(second,0,Total_Hours))%60 as varchar(2)),2) from  timesheet order by Date group by Task_Category where Date >=? and Date<=?"""
sq1 = db.execute(sql,(str(From),str(To)))

error: near "(": syntax error
```

How can I correct this?

Comment: Make sure all your parentheses are balanced.

Comment: @NPE: Yes I checked already. It fully balanced...

Comment: @MartijnPieters Can you help me out.. I didn't find any mistake in that..

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry ! actually, What i mean? I could not find the error, where i did?

Comment: @SivaSakthiVelan Can you check whether that query actually runs with the params in sqlite shell?

Comment: @mu無 I try to implementing query from this link : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/23503/2 .But this work perfectly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `right()` in SQLite; there is [no such function](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html). Use `substr()` instead:

```
substr(...., -2)
```

to get the last two characters.

You also need to fix the order of the `where`, `group by` and `order by` clauses; these have a [strict order](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html):

```
...
from timesheet
where Date >=? and Date<=?
group by Task_Category
order by Date
```

First comes `WHERE`, then `GROUP BY`, then `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Thanks...syntax error solved. But now its shows an another error :`no such column: second` .

Comment: That's not something I can help with in this post; you gave no Schema or expected output. You current question is solved.